# Is there a Google Gadget for Google Groups?

Tags: google-workspace, google-groups, google-classic-sites, gadget

Specifically, I am looking for something to tie in Discussions from a particular Group to a Google Site (to show recent discussions, say).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Google Map Maker](http://mapmaker.google.com)'s [community site](http://sites.google.com/site/mapyourworldcommunity/) integrates Google Groups in it. There's more information on how they do it at [Embedding Discussions](https://sites.google.com/site/embeddingdiscussions/) .

Comment: Turns out that for Google Apps (on your custom domain) this requires the new Google Apps infrastructure (http://googleenterprise.blogspot.com/2010/05/more-google-applications-coming-for.html) which we don't have yet but you can sign up for (https://spreadsheets1.google.com/a/tessera.co.uk/viewform?hl=en&formkey=dGdfTTA2eGhFT0c0SDVLXzMzMFNwUUE6MA#gid=0)